# Translation of "anyway" to mean "in spite of the mentioned fact"

Tags: phrase, colloquial

I want to translate "anyway" in the meaning of "in spite of the mentioned fact".

> This idea probably won't work, but let's try it anyway.

Can "auf jeden Fall", "irgendwie", "sowieso", "trotzdem", or "jedenfalls" go into the following blank?

> Diese Idee funktioniert wahrscheinlich nicht, aber probieren wir ***_*__**.

Comment: My choice is sowieso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following work:

> Diese Idee funktioniert wahrscheinlich nicht, aber probieren wir es trotzdem. (=despite, anyway)
>
> Diese Idee funktioniert wahrscheinlich nicht, aber probieren wir es irgendwie. (=somehow, clearly different meaning)
>
> Diese Idee funktioniert wahrscheinlich nicht, aber wir probieren es sowieso. (=The speaker knows that it will be tried despite everybody knows it's a bad idea, possibly because he knows that the group is known for doing stupid things).
>
> Diese Idee funktioniert wahrscheinlich nicht, aber probieren wir es in jedem Fall. (=We try it in any case)

"Jedenfalls" would technically also work, but would sound ancient here.

Comment: Die erste Variante scheint mir die Passenste.

Comment: Für den ersten Satz in der Frage auf jeden Fall, ja.

Comment: `... aber probieren wir sie allemal.` ist auch noch schön. :-)

Comment: Sowieso does not express the same. It should be taken out of the otherwise fine list... "so oder so" would be okay though

Comment: @Emanuel: That's what I tried to express with my explanation in parenthesis.